# Questions on parametric and non-parametric bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, frequentist

I am reading the chapter on Frequent Statistics from Kevin Murphy's book "*Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective*". The section on bootstrap reads:

> The bootstrap is a simple Monte Carlo technique to approximate the
>   sampling distribution. This is particularly useful in cases where the
>   estimator is a complex function of the true parameters.
>
> The idea is simple. If we knew the true parameters $θ^∗$ , we could
>   generate many (say $S$) fake datasets, each of size $N$, from the true
>   distribution, $x_i^s \sim p (·| θ^∗ )$, for $s = 1 : S, i = 1 : N$. 
>   We could then compute our estimator from each sample,
>   $\hat{\theta^s}=f (x^s_{1:N})$ and use the empirical distribution of
>   the resulting samples as our estimate of the sampling distribution.
>   Since $\theta$ is unknown, the idea of the **parametric bootstrap** is to
>   generate the samples using $\hat{\theta}(D)$ instead.
>
> An alternative, called the **non-parametric bootstrap**, is to sample the
>   $x^s_i$ (with replacement) from the original data $D$ , and then
>   compute the induced distribution as before. Some methods for speeding
>   up the bootstrap when applied to massive data sets are discussed in
>   (Kleiner et al. 2011).

- **1**. The text says:

  > If we knew the true parameters $\theta^*$ ... we could compute our
  >   estimator from each sample, $\hat{\theta^s}$...

but why would I use the estimator of each sample if I **already** know the  true parameters $\theta^*$?

- **2**. Also, what is the difference here between the empirical distribution and the sampling distribution?
- **3**. Finally, I don't quite understand the difference between **parametric** and **non-parametric** bootstrap from this text. They both infer $\theta$ from the set of observations $D$, but what is exactly the difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer given by miura is not entirely accurate so I am answering this old question for posterity:

(2). These are very different things. The empirical cdf is an estimate of the CDF (distribution) which generated the data. Precisely, it is the discrete CDF which assigns probability $1/n$ to each observed data point, $\hat{F}(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n I(X_i\leq x)$, for each $x$. This estimator converges to the true cdf: $\hat{F}(x) \to F(x) = P(X_i\leq x)$ almost surely for each $x$ (in fact uniformly).

The sampling distribution of a statistic $T$ is instead the distribution of the statistic you would expect to see under repeated experimentation. That is, you perform your experiment once and collect data ${X_1,\ldots,X_n}$. $T$ is a function of your data: $T = T(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. Now, suppose you repeat the experiment, and collect data ${X'_1,\ldots,X'_n}$. Recalculating T on the new sample gives $T' = T({X'_1,\ldots,X'_n})$. If we collected 100 samples we would have 100 estimates of $T$. These observations of $T$ form the sampling distribution of $T$. It is a true distribution. As the number of experiments goes to infinity its mean converges to $E(T)$ and its variance to $Var(T)$.

In general of course we don't repeat experiments like this, we only ever see one instance of $T$. Figuring out what the variance of $T$ is from a single observation is very difficult if you don't know the underlying probability function of $T$ a priori. Bootstrapping is a way to estimate that sampling distribution of $T$ by artificially running "new experiments" on which to calculate new instances of $T$. Each new sample is actually just a resample from the original data. That this provides you with more information than you have in the original data is mysterious and totally awesome.

(1). You are correct--you would not do this. The author is trying to motivate the parametric bootstrap by describing it as doing "what you would do if you knew the distribution" but substituting a very good estimator of the distribution function--the empirical cdf.

For example, suppose you know that your test statistic $T$ is normally distributed with mean zero, variance one. How would you estimate the sampling distribution of $T$?  Well, since you know the distribution, a silly and redundant way to estimate the sampling distribution is to use R to generate 10,000 or so standard normal random variables, then take their sample mean and variance, and use these as our estimates of the mean and variance of the sampling distribution of $T$.

If we *don't* know a priori the parameters of $T$, but we do know that it's normally distributed, what we can do instead is generate 10,000 or so samples from the empirical cdf, calculate $T$ on each of them, then take the sample mean and variance of these 10,000 $T$s, and use them as our estimates of the expected value and variance of $T$. Since the empirical cdf is a good estimator of the true cdf, the sample parameters should converge to the true parameters. This is the parametric bootstrap: you posit a model on the statistic you want to estimate. The model is indexed by a parameter, e.g. $(\mu, \sigma)$, which you estimate from repeated sampling from the ecdf.

(3). The nonparametric bootstrap doesn't even require you to know a priori that $T$ is normally distributed. Instead, you simply draw repeated samples from the ecdf, and calculate $T$ on each one. After you've drawn 10,000 or so samples and calculated 10,000 $T$s, you can plot a histogram of your estimates. This is a visualization of the sampling distribution of $T$. The nonparametric bootstrap won't tell you that the sampling distribution is normal, or gamma, or so on, but it allows you to estimate the sampling distribution (usually) as precisely as needed. It makes fewer assumptions and provides less information than the parametric bootstrap. It is less precise when the parametric assumption is true but more accurate when it is false. Which one you use in each situation you encounter depends entirely on context. Admittedly more people are familiar with the nonparametric bootstrap but frequently a weak parametric assumption makes a completely intractable model amenable to estimation, which is lovely.

Comment: I'm confused about your description of the parametric bootstrap "what we can do instead is generate 10,000 or so samples from the empirical cdf" My understanding of the parametric bootstrap is that you'd sample from a model you fit to the data. This is what the original quote from the Murphy book is describing. I could be misreading, but sampling from the empirical CDF of the data would be directly sampling the data points, which would be the standard bootstrap, no?

Comment: @user20160 you're misinterpreting the answer's "Instead": he is describing the nonparametric bootstrap, not the parametric one.

Answer (score 5):

I really appreciate the effort contributed by guest47, but I don't quite agree with his answer, in some minor aspects. I wouldn't directly pose my disagreements, but rather reflect them in this answer.

1. In many cases, it is redundant to compute $\hat\theta s$ when we already know the true underlying parameter $\theta*$. However, it is still useful when we want to look at the accuracy and precision of $\hat\theta s$ in estimating $\theta*$. Besides, the first paragraph in your quoted passage will make it easier for you to understand the notion of "parametric bootstrap", which I will touch upon shortly after.
2. Guest47 gives good answer. No need to elaborate more.
3. In parametric bootstrapping, what you have is the observed data D. You come up with a parametric model to fit the data, and use estimators $\hat\theta$ (which is a function of data D) for the true parameters $\theta*$. Then you generate thousands of datasets from the parametric model with $\hat\theta$, and estimate $\hat\theta s$ for these models. In nonparametric bootstrapping, you directly use D, sample (for thousands of times) exactly from D, instead of from generated data.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert, but for what it's worth:

1. Because you're interested in the sampling distribution, as mentioned in the first sentence of your quotation.
2. The empirical distribution is the distribution you see in your finite number of samples. The sampling distribution is what you would see were you to take an infinite number of samples.

I can't answer 3. 
I always understood what is described here as nonparametric bootstrap as "the" bootstrap.

If you have not already fully grasped the concept of the sampling distribution, there is a really nice [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34926/strategies-for-teaching-the-sampling-distribution) here that features very illustrative R code.

Comment: The difference between the parametric and nonparametric bootstrap is that the former generates its samples from the (assumed) distribution of the data, using the estimated parameter values, whereas the latter generates its samples by sampling with replacement from the observed data - no parametric model assumed.

Comment: @jbowman - the "non-parametric" bootstrap *does* have an underlying model - just that it is a different model to the one used to motivate the parameter estimate.

Comment: @miura Please don't vandalize your answer. If you want the asker to choose a different answer, comment under the question. If you want your answer deleted, please flag it and ask for that.