# Bootstrap to calculate confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, frequentist

I’ve seen two ways to use bootstrapping to estimate confidence intervals of parameters estimated via maximum likelihood

The first method fits the data with the assumed distribution. Then in a loop samples from that distribution N (same size as the original data) random numbers and refits using maximum likelihood. Repeat many times. Output is a list of parameter values.

The second method fits the data with the assumed distribution. Then samples with replacement from the original data a new set of data. Same number of elements as the original data. For each of these samples, fit using maximum likelihood.

Is one way better or more theoretically correct? I was trying to figure out which way is closer to the asymoptic assumptions in frequentist theory.

Comment: This post discusses parametric vs nonparametric bootstrap in more detail and may be helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47253/questions-on-parametric-and-non-parametric-bootstrap