# Sample distribution vs the distribution of the sample statistic

Tags: terminology, mean

I recently came across a statement in classwork that confused me:

> the sample distribution is the distribution of the sample

I wasn't sure about the validity of this statement. Specifically, shouldn't it have the word "statistic" at the end?

Comment: Can you provide some context? I'm not sure "distribution proportion" is all that common.

Comment: Ignore the second one, I can't find it my book either, just look at the first one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution of the *sample statistic* (i.e., if you add "statistic" to the end) is the [sampl*ing* distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_distribution).  That is a very different thing from the sample distribution.

The quoted text is correct: the distribution of the sample is the sample distribution.  The distribution that a sample statistic *would* have, if you repeated your study identically over and over indefinitely, is the sampling distribution.  It may help you to look at the figure at the top of my answer here:  [Strategies for teaching the sampling distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34952/7290).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose independent observations are drawn from a normal distribution with unknown mean $\mu$ and known standard deviation $\sigma = 1$.  Then the distribution of a sample of size $n$ is multivariate normal; i.e., if $$\boldsymbol X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n) \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\boldsymbol \mu, \boldsymbol \Sigma = I_n)$$ where $\boldsymbol \mu = (\mu, \ldots, \mu)$ and $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.  This is what we would call the **sample distribution**.  Now, if I use the sample to estimate the parameter $\mu$, then it's clear that one such estimator is the sample mean $$\bar x = (x_1 + \ldots + x_n)/n,$$ and the distribution of the sample mean, or the **sampling distribution of the sample mean** is simply univariate normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$; i.e., $$\bar x \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n}).$$  But since this is not the only possible statistic that estimates $\mu$, let alone the only statistic of interest in general, there exist other sampling distributions; how these might be distributed depends on the statistic that is derived from the sample.